# Laravel 4.2 - can't get random rows from database

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Can someone explain to me why this works

```
$profile = Profile::all()->random(8);
```

and this doesn't work

```
$profile = Profile::where('gender_id', '=', 1)->random(8);
```

I get the error saying

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::random()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use:

```
$profile = Profile::where('gender_id', '=', 1)->get()->random(8);
```

Because `random()` function gets random items from collection. [Reference](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_random)

Comment: This is the answer.  I misplaced get

Answer (score 4):

Add ->get()

```
$profile = Profile::where('gender_id', '=', 1)->get()->random(8);
```